# Android annotations gradle warning

Tags: android, gradle, android-annotations

I'm using **Android Studio 1.1 beta 4** with **gradle plugin 1.0.1** and trying to add Android Annotations to my project following the [official insturctions](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle). So I get the following **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.itloft.moneytracker"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}
def AAVersion = '3.2'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        resourcePackageName 'ru.itloft.moneytracker'

        // If you're using Android NBS flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
        // resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}
```

And all works fine, but I get a warning in the line `androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile` saying: **'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'**. How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: You said `gradle 1.0.1`. However, i guess this is not your gradle version, but the gradle android plugin version, am i right?

Comment: I went through a bit of a hard time setting AA on latest Android Studio, and left a blank project having it for anyone else. https://github.com/juanmendez/android-annotation-studio-demo

Comment: Thanks a ton. This one helped me.

Comment: You can ignore this warning, actually it is a false positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How @WonderCsabo already told this is a false positive. You can avoid this warning if you access the outputs explicit as collection

```
androidManifestFile variant.outputs.collect()[0].processResources.manifestFile
```